# MySQL Query Produces Empty Set

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I show the names of all artists that have not recorded any titles?  If I first run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Titles WHERE ArtistID is null;
```

It produces an empty set.

The tables in question look like this:

### Artists

ArtistID, ArtistName, City, Region, Country, EntryDate

### Titles

TitleID, ArtistID, Title, StudioID, UPC, Genre,

There are no null records for Artists or Titles, e.g., each record has some data. Since the above query produces an empty set, does this mean that all artists have recorded titles?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the following:

```
SELECT ArtistName FROM Artists WHERE NOT ArtistID IN (SELECT t.ArtistID FROM Titles t)
```

An other option, which probably is a bit faster but a bit harder to read:

```
SELECT ArtistName FROM Artists LEFT JOIN Titles ON Titles.ArtistID = Artists.ArtistID WHERE TitleID IS NULL
```

Comment: This seems logical. Thanks very much for the intelligent regsponse, Mr. Kostjens.

Comment: @cryptomath, if this solved your problem, please accept it so that others know this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Artists
WHERE artistID NOT IN (
    SELECT artistID  
    FROM Titles
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

> Since the above query produces an empty set, does this mean that all
>   artists have recorded titles?

No, it means that all titles have an associated artist.

To get artists without any titles you would have to do something like:

```
SELECT Artist.* 
FROM Artist 
WHERE ArtistId NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ArtistId FROM Titles)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Artists.* 
FROM Artists 
WHERE Artists.ArtistID NOT IN (SELECT Titles.ArtistID FROM Titles)
```

This should work. It can be written in other ways, but this should suffice.